# Filtering a table based on multiple values of a single column

Tags: oracle

I have a list of names in a specific column of a table. Is there a way to build a query which can pull out all the attributes of this names? I am a total novice so any help is appreciated

Example: User table

table columns:

- User id
- attributes
- user privileges
- 1st name
- 2nd name

The filter has to be applied based on a bunch of user first names.

Comment: Show sample data, filter data and result you need.

Comment: Sorry bunch! typo

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you are looking for the IN condition.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm

```
SELECT UserID, Attributes, UserPrivileges, 1stName, 2ndName
FROM User
WHERE 1stName IN ('John', 'Jane', 'Joseph', 'Laura');
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, It was the IN condition I was missing

Comment: If the answer helped you , could you mark it as correct?